# How to find the future date using SQL query?

Tags: infomaker

I have over 50K people in my system with their DOB under a tablename as Employee and column_name as Birthdate. i have report to generete to find how many people did actually turned 65 until todays date,and somebody turning 65 in future months ( AUGUST, SEP, OCT and so on). can somebody please help me how would i write that query ?

Comment: select * from employee where birthdate = 'sysdate - 23725' for somebody who are already turned as 65

Comment: 23725 basically was for (65X365 days) so somebody who has turned 65 , but couldnt find the way to solve the future dated ..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a sybase expert, but this should return all employees who are over 65 years as at 01 July 2014

```
select * from employee
where datediff(yy, Birthdate, "Jul 1, 2014") > 65
```

Source:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1550/html/blocks/X47295.htm (Google searched for sybase sql datediff)